# Different functions in every pin?

Tags: arduino

i have this microcontroller arduino ATmega328 for our project but im not familiar with this so im looking for some answers that can help me, so heres my question

1) in what pin can i assign my codes ?

2) is it possible to assign 2 different function ? for example pin# 1 (add) pin #2 (minus)

Answer (score 0):

The chip has its own processor. The pins either sink/source voltage as output pins or they detect presence of or lack of voltage as input pins. Each pin is controlled as part of a group called a register but can be assigned functions and used independently.

Using the above mentioned functions the processor can "sense" or interact with other input or output devices (ie temp sensor as input or LCD screen as output)

What function do you need it to perform?